# php for loop assign variables in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array (myArray) which looks like

```
Array(
  [0] => Computer
  [1] => House
  [2] => Phone
  )
```

I'm trying to set each value dynamically to a number for example

```
$newValues = [

  "computer" => 0,
  "House" => 1,
  "Phone" => 2,
];
```

I have the below loop

```
$y = 0;
for ($x = 0; $x < count($myArray); x++){
   $values = [
     $myArray[$x] = ($y+1)
   ];
   y++;


}
```

This incorrectly produces

```
Array(
  [0] => 3
 )
```

Comment: could be there repeated values?

Comment: No, repeated values have been filtered out already

Comment: you are just ressetting values every time. $value=

Comment: $values [$myArray[$x]]= ($y+1);
   y++;

Answer (score 2):

You can use array_flip($arr). 
[link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_flip.asp)

Answer (score 1):

If I good understand, you want to **flip values with keys**, so try to **use [`array_flip()`](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.array-flip.php).**

If becomes to work with array first try to do some research in [PHP Array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php). ;)

Answer (score 1):

use `array_flip()` which  — Exchanges all keys with their associated values in an array

```
<?php
$a1=array("0"=>"Computer","1"=>"House","2"=>"Phone");
$result=array_flip($a1);
print_r($result);
?>
```

then output is:

```
Array
(
    [Computer] => 0
    [House] => 1
    [Phone] => 2
)
```

for more information

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php

Comment: How can this be made dynamically, the values of the array will be changing constantly

Answer (score 0):

Like the others have said, array_flip will work, however, your actual problems in the code you've written are:

1. You are using the wrong assignment operator for array keys:

`$myArray[$x] = ($y+1)` should be `$myArray[$x] => ($y+1)`

However this type of assignment really isn't necessary as the next problems will show:

2. You are overwriting $values each iteration with a new array.

To append to $values, you could use:

```
$values[$myArray[$x]] = $y+1;
```

3. If you really  want 0 as your first value, don't use y+1 in your assignment.